# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem to compile my application, the reason is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect     ] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect     ]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

However, the jar is in pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <!-- <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>12.1.0.1</version> -->
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The class `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect` belong to the `hibernate-core` jar, not to the `ojdbc`. So, what hibernate version do you use?

Comment: It was added in hibernate 5.0.0.Beta1, See [HHH-9044](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9044)

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate changed the various dialects so that rather than including the version in the name, you just need to specify one. So there is no longer a `Oracle12cDialect` class. It's just `OracleDialect`. This is the case as of Hibernate 6 (`org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.+`)

If you're setting it through an application property (like in *Spring*) try:

```java
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
```

The old one would have been `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect`

Answer (score 1):

You can find hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect in **hibernate-core-5.0.11**.

Instead of OJDBC, upgrade your hibernate core dependency to,

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

or any version higher than 5.0.11